# Phusion Passenger - route exists but is not matched (gives 404 instead)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, passenger, apache-config

I'm running a rails 3 app at the root level in a phusion passenger environment (CentOS, apache) and having difficulty getting passenger to find some routes, although `rake routes` shows the routes correctly. Everything works fine in development (i.e. using `rails server` instead of phusion passenger in apache).

I have an admin section to my app with a login page. The main part of the app works, but everything under the admin section is inaccessible because I get a 404 instead of the login page (when I disable login I **can** access the admin pages). My apache config is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foo.bar.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/apps/myapp/current/public
  <Directory /var/www/apps/myapp/current/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My login process is implemented as a before_filter in an admin controller:

```
class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController

  # login disabled for testing
  before_filter :require_login

  def require_login
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
    redirect_to admin_login_path unless @current_user
  end
end
```

My routes file has

```
Mpf::Application.routes.draw do
  secure_protocol = "https://"
  ...
  namespace "admin" do
    ...
    match "login" => "user_sessions#new", :as => :login, :constraints => { :protocol => secure_protocol }
    ...    
  end
  ...
end
```

and when I run rake routes I get

```
admin_login        /admin/login(.:format)      {:protocol=>"http://", :action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/user_sessions"}
```

BUT when I try to access http://foo.bar.com/admin I get a 404 and the log shows

```
Started GET "/admin/login" for iii.iii.iii.iii at 2011-07-13 07:20:41 -0400
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/admin/login"):
```

As far as I can tell it should be working... except for the fact that it's not. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried accessing with `https://`? It looks like you provided constraints to prevent access from `http://` and the link you posted references `http://`.

Comment: Holy cow do I feel dumb now - that was in fact the problem. Thanks!